# How to vertically center all elements of array

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays

I want to put all elements of the array vertically centered. I have tried \arraystretch command to do so, but it is not working.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
     a4paper,
     total={170 mm,257 mm},
     left=20 mm,
     top=20 mm,
     }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\begin{document}

\indent \textbf{Step 2 :} \hspace{0.2 cm} Find the hexa-decimal equivalent of the integer part.
    \[
    \hspace{-2 cm}      
    \begin{array}{c|c|c}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5}
        \textbf{Radix} & \textbf{Integer} & \textbf{Remainder}\\
        \hline
         16 & 620 & \mathrm{C}\\
        \hline
         16 &  38 & 6\\
        \hline
         16 &   2 & 2\\
        \hline
            &   0 &  \\
    \end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

The output obtained from this code is as follows:

Output:

[image: Obtained output]

Can anyone help me to get the elements of array vertically centered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}`  numbers will looks better vertically centered:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\begin{document}

\indent \textbf{Step 2 :} \hspace{0.2 cm} Find the hexa-decimal equivalent of the integer part.
    \[\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}  % <---
    %\hspace{-2 cm}
    \begin{array}{c|c|c}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5}
        \textbf{Radix} & \textbf{Integer} & \textbf{Remainder}\\
        \hline
         16 & 620 & \mathrm{C}\\
        \hline
         16 &  38 & 6\\
        \hline
         16 &   2 & 2\\
        \hline
            &   0 &  \\
    \end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This helped me today. But, what can I do if I want the text to be aligned center automatically in all cells? Can I play with  `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}`? Thx

Comment: @Mikasa, For vertical centering are available many approaches. One of them is mentioned `extrarowheight`. If you placed in document preamble, it has effect in ask tables, You ay also consider `tabularray` package. For more, please ask a question, where you explain your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't play with `arraystretch` to vertically centre the contents of cells: it increases asymetrically the spaces at the top and at the bottom of cells. Use `cellspace`  instead, which enables you to define minimal vertical spacings at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`).

Unrelated: needless to load `amsfonts` if you load `amssymb` and `amsmath` if you load `amthtools`.

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
     a4paper,
     total={170 mm,257 mm},
     left=20 mm,
     top=20 mm,
     }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
%\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\begin{document}

    \[
    \hspace{-2 cm}
    \begin{array}{c|Sc|c}
        \textbf{Radix} & \textbf{Integer} & \textbf{Remainder}\\
        \hline
         16 & 620 & C\mathrm{C}\\
        \hline
         16 & 38 & 6\\
        \hline
         16 & 2 & 2\\
        \hline
            & 0 & \\
    \end{array}
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]