# The cellspace package doesn't work when an array cell contains \left(...\right)

Tags: math-mode, spacing, cellspace

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}
\[
    x = \left\{
    \begin{array}{cc} % using {Ccc} instead of {cc} doesn't work
    p\left(\ceil*{\frac{x}{y}}\right) & : 0 \\
    r\left(\ceil*{\frac{x}{y}}\right) & : 1 \\
    \end{array}
    \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

All I want is a bit of symmetric padding on the top and bottom of each array cell.
The cellspace package with the `math` option as suggested in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550569/how-to-vertically-center-all-elements-of-array) seemed like a clean solution.
But if the `\begin{array}{cc}` is replaced with `\begin{array}{Ccc}` to use a minimum cell padding provided by the cellspace package, the MWE breaks. (Replacing `\left(` with `(` and `\right)` with `)`  makes it work again.) Using `arraystretch` instead seems to add asymmetric padding (more on the top than the bottom).
How (if possible) can I make the cellspace package work in this example? If that is not possible, what other options do I have?

Comment: As far as I can see there are no `C` column specifiers defined. Please update your question to be able to actually show the problem. Using `Ccc` as suggested in the comment I just get an error about `C` not being defined.

Comment: The siunitx package should move the column specifier `S` to `C` as it uses `S` itself. (At least it does on my -- probably older -- version.) You should be able to comment out the loading of the siunitx package and use `Scc` to see the error.

Comment: Ahh, never noticed `siunitx` I'm on the new version, no idea what it does now. I don't think `S/C` sets the column in math mode after it has been applied. If you remove `siunitx` and use `S` (cellspace haven't been updated lately) then an Sc column in `array` complains about missing math mode.

Comment: Just checked `Sc` on `array` column containing `a_2` did not work in TL20, -19,-18. There are also no `array` env examples in the `cellspace` manual. Using `>{$} Sc <{$}` _does_ work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a workaround: using the `cases` environment, and `\addlinespace`  from `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}

\[
    x =
    \begin{cases}
    p\left(\ceil*{\frac{x}{y}}\right) & : 0 \\ \addlinespace
    r\left(\ceil*{\frac{x}{y}}\right) & : 1 \\
    \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not ``\\[1em]`` or similar

Comment: @daleif:  Well, there's a problem with this approach: when there is a fraction, as his the case, if the value of the vertical spacing is too small, you don't see any difference, so you have to determine it by trial and error, whereas with `\addlinespace`you always see a difference (possibly unsufficient, but you can use its optional argument).

Answer (score 1):

With `tblr` environment from the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), there is no much need to use `cellspace` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrInner{colsep=5pt} % default in array environmemt

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}

\section{Array}

\[
    x = \left\{
    \begin{array}{cc}
    p\left(\ceil*{\frac{x}{y}}\right) & : 0 \\
    r\left(\ceil*{\frac{x}{y}}\right) & : 1 \\
    \end{array}
    \right.
\]

\section{Tabularray}

\[
    x = \left\{
    \begin{tblr}{cc}
    p\left(\ceil*{\frac{x}{y}}\right) & : 0 \\
    r\left(\ceil*{\frac{x}{y}}\right) & : 1 \\
    \end{tblr}
    \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix` and its key `cell-space-limits`, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}
\[
    x = \left\{
    \begin{NiceArray}{cc}[cell-space-limits=5pt]
    p\left(\ceil*{\frac{x}{y}}\right) & : 0 \\
    r\left(\ceil*{\frac{x}{y}}\right) & : 1 \\
    \end{NiceArray}
    \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]